# When would #[account(signer)] constraint be used instead of Signer account type?

Tags: anchor

The [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html) page mentions:

> Consider using the Signer type if you would only have this constraint
> on the account.

What would be some examples where you would want to use the `#[account(signer)]` constraint instead of the `Signer` account type?

For example, when would you use something like this:

```
#[account(signer, <other constraints>)]
pub signer: SystemAccount<'info> // what other account types would require signing? maybe PDAs?
```

vs:

```
#[account(<other constraints>)]
pub signer: Signer<'info>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a style preference since both do the same thing.

With `#[account(signer)]` and `AccountInfo` you will also have to include the `CHECK:` rustdoc comment to explain why you're using an unsigned account.
But it makes things easier when I have to get the account info later in my program.

Rather than having a `Signer` Account type, I'll have to perform a `to_account_info` and clone the account in order to use/check account information.
This also improves DX since I instantly know that this is the signer.

**P.S this is prior to anchor 0.29.0**